# Dynamic number of integers using pointers and scanf()

Tags: c, pointers, scanf

The following code is supposed to read a dynamic number of integers. However, the output is confusing. I know that the problem can be solved using `scanf("%d", &mem_p[i])`. But why can't we use `mem_p++`? For me it says: give `%d` the address to the first integer and increment the pointer.

```
int num_el, i;
int *mem_p;

printf("Number of elements:");
scanf("%d", &num_el);
mem_p = (int *) calloc(num_el, sizeof(int));
printf("Enter %d numbers", num_el);

for(i = 0; i < num_el; i++) {
  scanf("%d", mem_p++);
}

printf("The numbers entered was: ");
for(i = 0; i < num_el; i++) {
  printf("%d ", mem_p[i]);
}
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
Number of elements:
3
Enter 3 numbers
11 22 33
The numbers entered was: 1737 3 1729
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use it if you keep a pointer to the original data:

```
mem_p = (int *) calloc(num_el, sizeof(int));
int* p = mem_p ;
printf("Enter %d numbers", num_el);

for(i = 0; i < num_el; i++) {
    scanf("%d", p++);
}
```

and then:

```
p = mem_p ;
printf("The numbers entered was: ");
for(i = 0; i < num_el; i++) {
    printf("%d ", *p++ );
}
```

You incremented the only pointer pointing to the entire array and at the end of the first for loop it didn't point to the array anymore.